Using parallelization in numba is better for one algorithm, but not for another similar algorithm?
I am making a simulation of N particles with the same mass and random velocities. I want to compute the total energy and total momentum of the system. I considered 4 approaches and wanted to benchmark them to see which one performs best:

Using regular numpy routines and computations.
Using numba.jit and writing the for loop myself.
Using numba.jit with parallel=True to utilize multiple cores.
Using a hybrid version of the last two approaches based on the number of particles. If we don't have enough particles, the overhead of parallelization isn't worth it.

Here's the code for the energy calculation:
from functools import wraps

import numpy as np
import numba as nb
import numpy.typing as npt
import perfplot

jit_opts = dict(
    nopython=True, nogil=True, cache=False, error_model="numpy", fastmath=True
)

rng = np.random.default_rng()


def hybrid_parallel_jit(get_threshold, *hpj_args, default_threshold=None, **hpj_kwargs):
    def _hybrid_parallel_jit(func):
        if "parallel" in hpj_kwargs:
            raise ValueError("Cannot specify 'parallel' for hybrid jitted function")
        hpj_kwargs["parallel"] = True
        func_parallel = nb.jit(*hpj_args, **hpj_kwargs)(func)
        hpj_kwargs["parallel"] = False
        func_non_parallel = nb.jit(*hpj_args, **hpj_kwargs)(func)

        @wraps(func)
        def hybrid_func(*args, threshold=None, **kwargs):
            if threshold is None:
                threshold = default_threshold
                if threshold is None:
                    raise ValueError(
                        "`threshold` keyword argument was not provided, and a "
                        "default threshold was not set either."
                    )
            return (
                func_non_parallel(*args, **kwargs)
                if get_threshold(*args, **kwargs) < threshold
                else func_parallel(*args, **kwargs)
            )

        return hybrid_func

    return _hybrid_parallel_jit


def random_unit_vectors(n: int) -> npt.NDArray[float]:
    phi = rng.uniform(0, 2 * np.pi, n)
    cos_theta = rng.uniform(-1, 1, n)
    sin_theta = np.sqrt(1 - cos_theta**2)
    return np.column_stack(
        (sin_theta * np.cos(phi), sin_theta * np.sin(phi), cos_theta)
    )


@nb.jit([nb.float64(nb.float64[:, :])], **jit_opts)
def total_energy(velocities: npt.NDArray[float]) -> float:
    energy = 0
    for i in range(velocities.shape[0]):
        energy += velocities[i, 0] ** 2 + velocities[i, 1] ** 2 + velocities[i, 2] ** 2
    return energy / 2


@nb.jit([nb.float64(nb.float64[:, :])], parallel=True, **jit_opts)
def total_energy_parallel(velocities: npt.NDArray[float]) -> float:
    energy = 0
    for i in nb.prange(velocities.shape[0]):
        energy += velocities[i, 0] ** 2 + velocities[i, 1] ** 2 + velocities[i, 2] ** 2
    return energy / 2


def total_energy_numpy(velocities: npt.NDArray[float]) -> float:
    return np.einsum("ij, ij->", velocities, velocities) / 2


@hybrid_parallel_jit(
    lambda v: v.shape[0],
    [nb.float64(nb.float64[:, :])],
    **jit_opts,
)
def total_energy_improved(velocities: npt.NDArray[float]) -> float:
    energy = 0
    for i in nb.prange(velocities.shape[0]):
        energy += velocities[i, 0] ** 2 + velocities[i, 1] ** 2 + velocities[i, 2] ** 2
    return energy / 2


perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: random_unit_vectors(n),
    kernels=[
        lambda v: total_energy_numpy(v),
        lambda v: total_energy(v),
        lambda v: total_energy_parallel(v),
        lambda v: total_energy_improved(v, threshold=10_000),
    ],
    labels=["numpy", "numba", "numba parallel", "numba improved"],
    n_range=[10**k for k in range(9)],
    xlabel="len(a)",
)

The @hybrid_parallel_jit decorator basically calls the parallel version if N is bigger than a specified threshold and calls the non-parallel version otherwise. The results I got from running this:

These results match my expectations: The parallel versions are better for large N (larger than 10,000 on my machine) and the non-parallel versions are better for smaller N. It looks like the hybrid version (option 4) is the overall best option.
I modified the code to make a similar tests for the momentum calculations:
from functools import wraps

import numpy as np
import numba as nb
import numpy.typing as npt
import perfplot

jit_opts = dict(
    nopython=True, nogil=True, cache=False, error_model="numpy", fastmath=True
)

rng = np.random.default_rng()


def hybrid_parallel_jit(get_threshold, *hpj_args, default_threshold=None, **hpj_kwargs):
    def _hybrid_parallel_jit(func):
        if "parallel" in hpj_kwargs:
            raise ValueError("Cannot specify 'parallel' for hybrid jitted function")
        hpj_kwargs["parallel"] = True
        func_parallel = nb.jit(*hpj_args, **hpj_kwargs)(func)
        hpj_kwargs["parallel"] = False
        func_non_parallel = nb.jit(*hpj_args, **hpj_kwargs)(func)

        @wraps(func)
        def hybrid_func(*args, threshold=None, **kwargs):
            if threshold is None:
                threshold = default_threshold
                if threshold is None:
                    raise ValueError(
                        "`threshold` keyword argument was not provided, and a "
                        "default threshold was not set either."
                    )
            return (
                func_non_parallel(*args, **kwargs)
                if get_threshold(*args, **kwargs) < threshold
                else func_parallel(*args, **kwargs)
            )

        return hybrid_func

    return _hybrid_parallel_jit


def random_unit_vectors(n: int) -> npt.NDArray[float]:
    phi = rng.uniform(0, 2 * np.pi, n)
    cos_theta = rng.uniform(-1, 1, n)
    sin_theta = np.sqrt(1 - cos_theta**2)
    return np.column_stack(
        (sin_theta * np.cos(phi), sin_theta * np.sin(phi), cos_theta)
    )


@nb.jit([nb.float64[:](nb.float64[:, :])], **jit_opts)
def total_momentum(velocities: npt.NDArray[float]) -> float:
    momentum = np.zeros(3)
    for i in range(velocities.shape[0]):
        momentum += velocities[i]
    return momentum


@nb.jit([nb.float64[:](nb.float64[:, :])], parallel=True, **jit_opts)
def total_momentum_parallel(velocities: npt.NDArray[float]) -> float:
    momentum = np.zeros(3)
    for i in nb.prange(velocities.shape[0]):
        momentum += velocities[i]
    return momentum


def total_momentum_numpy(velocities: npt.NDArray[float]) -> float:
    return np.sum(velocities, axis=0)


@hybrid_parallel_jit(
    lambda v: v.shape[0],
    [nb.float64[:](nb.float64[:, :])],
    **jit_opts,
)
def total_momentum_improved(velocities: npt.NDArray[float]) -> float:
    momentum = np.zeros(3)
    for i in nb.prange(velocities.shape[0]):
        momentum += velocities[i]
    return momentum


perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: random_unit_vectors(n),
    kernels=[
        lambda v: total_momentum_numpy(v),
        lambda v: total_momentum(v),
        lambda v: total_momentum_parallel(v),
        lambda v: total_momentum_improved(v, threshold=10_000),
    ],
    labels=["numpy", "numba", "numba parallel", "numba improved"],
    n_range=[10**k for k in range(9)],
    xlabel="len(a)",
)

The momentum calculation is very similar to the energy calculation, so I expected to get a similar graph and the same conclusion that option 4 works best. However, when I ran the code I got:

The non-parallel numba version is the fastest both for small and large N. These results are very surprising to me. The momentum calculation is very similar to the energy. In both cases, I sum the velocities in some way that seems straight forward in terms of runtime cost. Can somebody explain why I get such different results for these two very similar calculations? More specifically, why using parallelization doesn't seem to help with the momentum calculation even for large N? Any insights into what's going on here would be appreciated.

Looking at your function:
@nb.jit([nb.float64[:](nb.float64[:, :])], parallel=True, **jit_opts)
def total_momentum_parallel(velocities: npt.NDArray[float]) -> float:
    momentum = np.zeros(3)
    for i in nb.prange(velocities.shape[0]):
        momentum += velocities[i]
    return momentum

reveals that every thread is attempting to access the same memory location (in this case momentum) at the same time.
Of course this means some overhead (locking) to not corrupt data. Try to change the line momentum += velocities[i] to:
momentum[0] += velocities[i, 0]
momentum[1] += velocities[i, 1]
momentum[2] += velocities[i, 2]

and now the function won't work.
The remedy is to allocate the momentum vector for each thread and at the end sum the vectors, e.g.:
@nb.jit([nb.float64[:](nb.float64[:, :])], parallel=True, **jit_opts)
def total_momentum_parallel(velocities: npt.NDArray[float]) -> float:
    N = nb.get_num_threads()
    rows = velocities.shape[0]

    chunks = rows // N + 1
    momentum = np.zeros(shape=(N, 3))

    for thread_idx in nb.prange(N):
        for i in range(chunks * thread_idx, chunks * (thread_idx + 1)):
            if i >= rows:
                break
            momentum[thread_idx, 0] += velocities[i, 0]
            momentum[thread_idx, 1] += velocities[i, 1]
            momentum[thread_idx, 2] += velocities[i, 2]

    return momentum.sum(axis=0)

Benchmarking this function yields this graph on my AMD 5700x:

Now you see the parallel version is the fastest.

EDIT: After discussion in the comments I come up with different version of the parallel function that is slightly faster than the first proposed version:
@nb.jit([nb.float64[:](nb.float64[:, :])], parallel=True, **jit_opts)
def total_momentum_parallel_2(velocities: npt.NDArray[float]) -> float:
    mx, my, mz = 0, 0, 0
    for i in nb.prange(velocities.shape[0]):
        mx += velocities[i, 0]
        my += velocities[i, 1]
        mz += velocities[i, 2]
    return np.array([mx, my, mz], dtype="float64")

yields this graph:


Interesting. I will test it tomorrow and share my results. I was under the impression that numba handles these things automatically. If what you’re saying is true, then it leaves me wondering why the energy function worked as expected. We have a similar case there where each thread needs to access the energy variable so it probably has to lock it as well to avoid corruption. The only difference between this and the momentum function is that energy is a scalar variable while momentum is a vector variable.

@ShaiAvr Yes, numba has handled this situation automatically (thats why you see correct result), but the speed isn't optimal. And yes, energy is scalar so this is probably atomic operation that doesn't involve any locking.

It also means I need to think harder on how to implement my @hybrid_parallel_jit decorator since the difference between the code of the parallel and non parallel versions is more significant. I hope it can still work for me :)

If using scalars doesn’t involve any locking, then why setting the three components of the vector manually wouldn’t work? Aren’t the three components simply scalars? It sounds that using three scalar variables and constructing the vector at the end would work, which is confusing to me.

@ShaiAvr momentum[0] += velocities[i, 0] is syntactic sugar for momentum[0] = momentum[0] + velocities[i, 0]. Remember, multiple threads are doing this operation. So one thread could set momentum[0] and second thread still holds old value for momentum[0]

Also, in your answer, is it possible to set the entire vector at once in the parallel loop, or do we have to set individual components?

@ShaiAvr You can experiment with different configurations. Also removing this if i >= rows and doing rest of the chunks in separate loop etc.

Doesn’t the same logic apply to scalars? energy += … is syntactic sugar for energy = energy + … so this becomes an issue with multiple threads, no?

@ShaiAvr energy is scalar, momentum[0] is memory location to dynamically allocated memory, so this is probably compiled differently (just guessing, you can always inspect the compiled code)

@ShaiAvr After this discussion I've edited my answer and added new version of the parallel function (now using 3 scalars). It's slightly fastest than the original version proposed, but for arrays 10**7 and up the speed is the same (memory bound)

I am not aware of any automatic locking in Numba. (implicit) Allocations can cause such an effect though because they are not only slow but also tends to be serialized currently (which often cause performance issue). I reported an issue about this. Things have been improved a bit since, but it is still often an issue. Note that races conditions tends to cause a serialization of the access and decrease sharply the performance (due to cache line bounding).

Structuring arrays with a shape of like (N, 3) is inefficient. It prevent most SIMD vectorization. This is pretty important since vectorized codes can typically be 2 to 8 times faster (on x86-64 CPUs). Instead, you should use a transposed shape : (3, N). It also makes (parallel) reduction simpler: np.sum(array[c,:]) for component c. I think Numba should automatically parallelize that if parallel=True is set. It should also be faster with Numpy (and CuPy). However, here, for large array, it will have no impact due to the operation being memory bound.

@JérômeRichard Can you elaborate on your point about the shape (N, 3) vs (3, N) or link to an article or something? I didn't think that the shape of the array could impact the performance of the algorithm.

@ShaiAvr This is similar to the "AoS vs SoA" problem (the fact that items are in a structure or in an array does not matter -- what matters is the memory layout and the memory access pattern). You can read more about this here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AoS_and_SoA. There are few cases where AoS can be efficient but generally not in numerical codes like in your case. Similarly you can find posts about it.

@JérômeRichard I just tested (N, 3) vs (3, N). For the numpy solution, indeed (3, N) is slightly faster than (N, 3). However, for the numba solutions, both the parallel and the non-parallel versions, run about the same time and are still way faster than numpy.

@ShaiAvr If your array is sufficiently big then, the code will be memory bound, especially when it cannot fit in cache anymore. At this point, using a computationally more efficient approach does not have much impact since the memory is the main bottleneck. This is certainly what you observe and why the code are about equally fast

@JérômeRichard But for the numba versions, I literally get the same graph, both for large n and small n. Only the numpy version seems to benefit from using (3, N) instead of (N, 3). Besides, how can numba even utilize SIMD vectorization if I write the for loop myself?

@ShaiAvr Interesting results. The code of Numpy is statically compiled (generally with GCC) with runtime-defined strides often preventing automatic vectorization (done by compilers). Not to mention compilers are often not so good in this case. Thus, Numpy developers do the vectorization manually for some functions. The thing is this manual vectorization is always for simple cases, not for (N,3), (N,4), (N,2). GCC sometimes generate a code for (N,4) or (N,8) but it is rather inefficient due to the way Numpy is designed internally.

@ShaiAvr Regarding Numba, the code is dynamically compiled using the LLVM stack (behaving differently from GCC). The JIT can have more information than the code of Numpy (the specific Numba code is more specialized). Thus, maybe Numba (LLVM) can vectorize this specific cases (and few similar). There is a way using shuffle though this is always less efficient than using a better layout in pure compute-bound codes (not even limited by the CPU cache). Using shuffle can be enough for code partially/fully memory-bound. To be sure, one need to check the generated assembly code.

@ShaiAvr Note that such optimization doing shuffle is rather brittle (and relatively new) so compilers can miss it in complex loops (significantly more than ones using a better layout). Note that the results are also dependent of the specific target CPU (eg. the M1 is less affected by this than Ryzen CPU which are less affected than server Intel CPUs). On GPU, the layout is critical (due to wider SIMD units) and (N,3) should always perform much worst than (3,N) except when DRAM is the bottleneck (one can still do shuffles but it is not done automatically and quite-complex to do manually).
